# Button input does not work with rxjs fromEvent

Tags: angular, reactjs

I am trying to make a button click event subscribe to an observable.

However I can't seem to get the buttom to work with the fromEvent.

What am I missing?

I have a button:

```
<button mat-raised-button #searchButton>Search</button>
```

In my typescript file I have:

```
@ViewChild('searchButton') searchButton: ElementRef;

ngAfterViewInit() {

    fromEvent<MouseEvent>(this.searchButton.nativeElement, 'click')
      .pipe(
        debounceTime(150),
        distinctUntilChanged(),
      tap(() => {
        alert("SEARCH WAS CLICKED");
          this.paginator.pageIndex = 0;
          this.loadData();
        })
      )
      .subscribe();          
  }
```

EDIT:

This works with an input box.

```
@ViewChild('searchString') searchString: ElementRef;

fromEvent<MouseEvent>(this.searchString.nativeElement, 'click')
```

Comment: you should pass a function in your subscribe: `.subscribe(() => void 0);`

Comment: which rxjs version are you using? there was a bug related to this behavior in rxjs 5.x which was resolved in v. 5.4.2

Comment: How do I determine the version?  I don't see anything about rxjs when I run ng --version

Comment: I am running version 5.5.10

Comment: If the button is inside a structural directive, it may not be present in the DOM when you call `fromEvent`. Did you check if `this.searchButton.nativeElement` is valid before subscribing to the `click` event?

Comment: I have not.  I am still learning Angular as I go.  I will check and see if that is the issue.

Comment: I am seeing the following error in the browser debug. Invalid event target

Comment: You are correct.  this.searchButton.nativeElement is undefined.  However I'm not sure why that is the case.  I don't see the button in a structural directive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who has the same issue.

I was using a material button and to get it to work I had to do the following:

```
@ViewChild('searchButton') searchButton: any;

fromEvent(this.searchButton._elementRef.nativeElement, "click")
```

Comment: You could also do `@ViewChild('searchButton', {read: ElementRef}) searchButton: ElementRef;` instead of `._elementRef`

Answer (score 0):

## Summary

- If you want a reference to the `MatButton` instance, you should do:

  ```js
  @ViewChild('matbut')
  matButton: MatButton;
  ```
- If you only need the **native element** for binding an event, you should do:

  ```js
  @ViewChild('some-buttom', {read: ElementRef})
  button: ElementRef;
  ```